# Outlook Add-In and Disabling/Hiding Custom Menu Items

Tags: c#, outlook, ribbon, outlook-addin, office-interop

I've created an Outlook Add-In, and I'm using an XML ribbon configuration file to specify a new tab, and button. The button loads into a new tab within outlook. Now sometimes, based on user we want to be able to hide or disable these buttons. What's the simplest way to disable a menu button on a custom tab through the Outlook Interop api?

My first guess is that I need to iterate through some command bar collections after my ribbon is created, and then search for my menu buttons, but I'm not sure where these collections are.

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    this.ribbon = new MyRibbon();

    // loop through tabs and ribbon items, look for my custom control, and enabled/disable specific buttons.

    return this.ribbon;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question. Finally figured it out. Within the xml configuration there is a getVisible callback for buttons/groups/tabs.

So all you need to do is add the callback in the xml, in my case I did it for a group:

```
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idQ="myNs:myTab" label="My Label" >
          <group id="settingsGroup" label="Settings" getVisible="Control_Visible" >
              <button id="preferences" label="Preferences" image="configuration.png"
      screentip="Preferences" size="large" onAction="Settings_Click" supertip="Preferences" />
          </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

and create a callback method

```
public bool Control_Visible(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    // In order to maintain a reference to the groups, I store the controls into a List<Office.IRibbonControl>.
    if(!this.groupControls.Contains(control))
    {
        this.groupControls.Add(control);
    }         

    // logic here to determine if it should return true or false to be visible...
    return true;
}
```

Then if during the use of outlook, you change the visibility setting of a button/tab/group, you need to call Invalidate() method on the ribbon so the ribbon redraws. IE:

```
this.ribbon.Invalidate();
```